# running p5.js examples on digitalocean: model does not load

Tags: digital-ocean, p5.js

I downloaded the examples from `https://ml5js.org/getting-started/running-examples/` and run them on `digital ocean` server.

```
cd /path/to/ml5-examples
python -m http.server 8081
```

I am running the `p5js/PoseNet/PoseNet_webcam/` example
But, it just displays the following, without loading any model.

```
PoseNet example using p5.js
Loading model...
```

What i want is to get video stream from webcam on remote server.

EDIT:

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started with ml5.js</title>
    <!-- p5 -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ml5 -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ml5@0.3.1/dist/ml5.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      // Your code will go here
      // open up your console - if everything loaded properly you should see 0.3.1
      console.log('ml5 version:', ml5.version);
      let capture;

      function setup() {
        createCanvas(390, 240);
        capture = createCapture(VIDEO);
        capture.size(320, 240);
        //capture.hide();
      }

      function draw() {
        background(255);
        image(capture, 0, 0, 320, 240);
        filter(INVERT);
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JS console gives the following error:

```
  Error: getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser
        at Object.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia (p5.dom.min.js:3)
        at m.d.createCapture (p5.dom.min.js:3)
        at setup ((index):29)
        at m.<anonymous> (p5.min.js:3)
        at m.<anonymous> (p5.min.js:3)
        at new m (p5.min.js:3)
        at n (p5.min.js:3)
```

When i open the program as a local file on the same Chrome browser, there is no error. I only get the error when i run my program on a cloud server.

Comment: Have you tried checking your JavaScript console for errors?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Thank you for the reply. I just edited my post with error from JS console!

Comment: Don't add the "processing.js" tag if you're not using the (now defunct) processing.js library.

Comment: @user2698178 I have the same problem. Did you ever found a solution?